# Reducir el código

Tags: javascript

Estoy iniciando y he hecho un programa que calcula tu peso en los diferentes planetas del sistema solar.

En el tengo esta función que hace el calculo según los datos que introduzca el usuario:

```
function calcular()
{
    var peso = document.form.peso.value;
    var planeta = document.form.planeta.value;
    if (planeta == "Mercurio")
    {
        peso_final = peso * gmer / gtie;
        nombre = "Mercurio";
    }
    else if (planeta == "Venus")
    {
        peso_final = peso * gven / gtie;
        nombre = "Venus";
    }
    else if (planeta == "Tierra")
    {
        peso_final = peso * gtie / gtie;
        nombre = "la Tierra";
    }
    else if (planeta == "Marte")
    {
        peso_final = peso * gmar / gtie;
        nombre = "Marte";
    }
    else if (planeta == "Júpiter")
    {
        peso_final = peso * gjup / gtie;
        nombre = "Júpiter";
    }
    else if (planeta == "Saturno")
    {
        peso_final = peso * gsat / gtie;
        nombre = "Saturno";
    }
    else if (planeta == "Urano")
    {
        peso_final = peso * gura / gtie;
        nombre = "Urano";
    }
    else if (planeta == "Neptuno")
    {
        peso_final = peso * gnep / gtie;
        nombre = "Neptuno";
    }
    else
    {
        peso_final = 1000000;
        nombre = "Kryptón";
    }
    result.innerHTML = 
        "<h1>" + nombre + "</h2>" +
        "<h2>Tu peso en " + nombre + " seria de " + parseInt(peso_final) + " Kilos</h2>"
    ;
}
```

Mi duda es si es necesario hacer una condición por cada planeta?
Como podría reducirlo?

Perdonen si es algo muy simple pero llevo muy poco tiempo en esto.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario. En general, para lograrlo se ocupa polimorfismo. Sin embargo, en este caso, no es necesario y basta con crear un diccionario:

```
var planetas = {
  'tierra': {nombre: 'tierra', g: 10},
  'venus': {nombre: 'venus', g: 30},
  //etc
};
```

Vas rellenando con toda la información necesaria para hacer el calculo.

Luego, solo tienes que seleccionas un planeta:

```
planetaSeleccionado = planetas[planeta];
```

Esta variable va a tener la información sobre el planeta seleccionado.

Por lo tanto, puedes calcular el peso final usando esa información:

```
peso_final = peso * planetaSeleccionado.g / planetas['tierra'].g;
```

Comment: Mas que un diccionario sería un objeto

Comment: @BetaM En *JavaScript* es algo confuso por la propia terminología del lenguaje. Pero técnicamente es un diccionario o *map* ya que es una colección de pares clave-valor.

Comment: Gracias, he conseguido reducir de 85 lineas de código a 46.

Answer (score 0):

Si que podrías ahórrate los ifs si creas una array usando los nombres de los planetas y como valor los datos que necesites para calcularlo por ejemplo:

```
planetas = [
'Mercurio' : <valor podría ser el resultado ya calculado de gmer / gtie>
'Venus' : <valor podría ser el resultado ya calculado de gven / gtie>
etc ...
]
```

luego acceder a esos valores por la clave que es la que pone el usuario, al final tu algoritmo sería así:

```
 peso_final = planetas[planeta] * peso ;
```