# Reducir lineas de codígo en python. Es posible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se trata de conocer el peso en algunos planetas sistema solar y la luna de un determinado objeto.
En la Tierra el valor de la Gravedad es 9.81 N/Kg (Newtons por kilo). En la Luna por ejemplo el valor es de 1.622 N/Kg.
La formula es facil-->Peso en la Luna = (Peso en la Tierra / 9.81) * 1.622.

Yo hice este programa:

```
#Input
Peso_en_Tierra = float(input("Intro el peso en kgs: "))

#Process - Calcular el peso en los distintos planetas, con dos decimales.
Peso_en_Luna = round(Peso_en_Tierra * 1.622 / 9.81 , 2)
Peso_en_Mercurio = round(Peso_en_Tierra * 3.7 / 9.81, 2)
Peso_en_Venus = round(Peso_en_Tierra * 8.87 / 9.81, 2)
Peso_en_Marte = round(Peso_en_Tierra * 3.711 / 9.81, 2)
Peso_en_Jupiter = round(Peso_en_Tierra * 24.79 / 9.81, 2)
Peso_en_Saturno = round(Peso_en_Tierra * 10.44 / 9.81, 2)
Peso_en_Urano = round(Peso_en_Tierra * 8.69 / 9.81, 2)
Peso_en_Neptuno = round(Peso_en_Tierra * 11.15 / 9.81, 2)


#Output
print("El peso en la Luna es de: " + str(Peso_en_Luna) + "kg.")
print("El peso en Mercurio es de: " + str(Peso_en_Mercurio) + "kg.")
print("El peso en Venus es de: " + str(Peso_en_Venus) + "kg.")
print("El peso en Marte es de: " + str(Peso_en_Marte) + "kg.")
print("El peso en Jupiter es de: " + str(Peso_en_Jupiter) + "kg.")
print("El peso en Saturno es de: " + str(Peso_en_Saturno) + "kg.")
print("El peso en Urano es de: " + str(Peso_en_Urano) + "kg.")
print("El peso en Neptuno es de: " + str(Peso_en_Neptuno) + "kg.")
```

Soy novato en Python y lo que me gustaria es necesitar menos lineas de codigo. ¿Es posible?.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Reducir el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359200/reducir-el-c%c3%b3digo)

Comment: Es el mismo problema a solucionar, pero desconozco javascript y las soluciones que se proponen me resultaban muy confusas...para mi nivel.

Comment: OK ... son tan parecidos ... pero en fin ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que es posible, si entiendes tú código de forma más abstracta. Se podría decir que tienes un conjunto de planetas (o satélites) y cada uno tiene una relación con el peso en la tierra. Si lo piensas de esta forma, podrías recorrer ese conjunto de datos y dentro de un ciclo mostrar los pesos finales.

Este conjunto podría ser una lista dónde cada elemento sea una tupla con los dos datos importantes, nombre y la relación con el peso terrestre:

```
planetas = [
  ("Tierra", 9.81),
  ("Luna", 1.622),
  ("Mercurio",3.7)
]

Peso_en_Tierra = 10
for planeta in planetas:
  print("El peso en {0} es de: {1} kg.".format(planeta[0], 
                                               round(Peso_en_Tierra * planeta[1] / 9.81,2)))

El peso en Tierra es de: 10.0 kg.
El peso en Luna es de: 1.65 kg.
El peso en Mercurio es de: 3.77 kg.
```

Un poco lo que rompe esta lógica genérica, es que la luna tiene género ;), obviando esto, simplemente deberías tomarte el trabajo de completar la lista.

PD: Como idea general, es muy bueno ejercitar la capacidad de identificar patrones repetitivos en el código, que generalmente terminan siendo candidatos a ser reemplazados por ciclos.

Comment: Eso es lo que buscaba. Otra forma de acercarme al problema. Y otra forma de dcirlo. PIenso que mi cogido es muy rigido. Supongo que es normal en los principios del aprendizaje. Gracias por el ejemplo. Me resulta muy útil

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a SO ES DoctorChocolate c:
Si es posible gracias al uso de tuplas, listas y bucles for:

```
Peso_en_Tierra = float(input("Intro el peso en kgs: "))

gravity = (("luna", 1.622), ("mercurio", 3.7), ("venus", 8.87), ("marte", 3.711))
pesos = []

for mundo, g in gravity:
    pesos.append((mundo, Peso_en_Tierra * g / 9.81))
for mundo, peso in pesos:
    print("El peso en %s es de: %f" % (mundo.capitalize(), peso))
```

O bien podrías hacer que pesos sea un diccionario y luego acceder al peso que tendría el objeto en un mundo especifico con `pesos["luna"]`:
Peso_en_Tierra = float(input("Intro el peso en kgs: "))

```
gravity = (("luna", 1.622), ("mercurio", 3.7), ("venus", 8.87), ("marte", 3.711))
pesos = {}

for mundo, g in gravity:
    pesos[mundo]=round(Peso_en_Tierra * g / 9.81, 2)

for mundo, peso in pesos.items():
    print("El peso en %s es de: %f" % (mundo.capitalize(), peso))
```

No hice todos los planetas para ahorrarme algo de trabajo.
Más información sobre lo que mencioné antes aqui: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/listas-y-tuplas/
https://devcode.la/tutoriales/diccionarios-en-python/

Comment: Gracias. Los enlaces me son muy utiles par comprender mejor vuestros ejemplos. Salud